# Create variable from memory

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using sfml.  I need to write a function that will create a type sf::RectangleShape and return a new sf::RectangleShape with the position of the mouse at the current time and stay there after I use window.draw() Right now my code is:

```
sf::RectangleShape functions::Map(sf::RectangleShape wall0){

    wall0.setPosition(0,0);
    wall0.setSize(sf::Vector2f(200,200));
    wall0.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    wall0 = this->wall0;
    return wall0;
}

void functions::Draw(){

    window.clear();
    window.draw(logo);
    if (menu){

        window.draw(menuStart);
            window.draw(menuOptions);
            window.draw(menuExit);
    }
    if (playing){
       void Map();
       window.draw(wall0);
       if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)){



    }



}
```

I want to return wall0 with the new mouse position when the left mouse button is pressed.  I know how to get the mouse input but not how to draw the object and keep it on the window.  I've gotten it to where it draws the object while the mouse button is clicked but it doesn't stay.

Comment: `this->wall0`?? show `Map` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sfml - but briefly looking at your code this is what I think you want to do:

```
void functions::Map(sf::RectangleShape & wall0){

    wall0.setPosition(0,0);
    wall0.setSize(sf::Vector2f(200,200));
    wall0.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
}
```

Then functions::Draw method:

```
...
if (playing){
   window.draw( Map(wall00) );
   if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)){
   ...
```

Comment: No that didn't work I get the error too many functions in call and window.draw no instance of overloaded function

Comment: is functions::Map a function or class member? Try functions::Map(wall0) ?

Comment: Hm now I just have no instance of overloaded function...annot convert parameter 1 from 'void' to 'const sf::Drawable &'

Comment: instead of saying "void Map();" did you mean to say "wall0 = Map(wall0);" ?